# Using function New-InputBox in a script adds a letter in the output

Tags: powershell

```
function New-InputBox
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Mailbox,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$UserID
    )
    Add-MailboxPermission -identity $mailbox -user $userid@psu.edu -AccessRights FullAccess -Verbose -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping $true
    Add-RecipientPermission -identity $mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $userid@psu.edu -verbose -confirm:$false
}
Show-Command -Name New-InputBox
```

The output provides 2 input box fields.
But the output window shows a m at the end of the second input box which I have to backspace over and hit enter for the script to continue.
If I hit enter right away it always fails because of the m.
This works perfect in Powershell ISE.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `PSVersion 5.1.19041.1645`. Tested e.g. `Show-Command -Name Get-ChildItem` and it shows a `m` at the end of the last parameter (even common parameters), for instance checked `Verbose` results to `Get-ChildItem  -Verbosem`… Fixed in `PSVersion 7.2.2`.

Comment: And for a cmdlet without parameter: `Show-Command -Name Get-WinUserLanguageList  -NoCommonParameter` yields `Get-WinUserLanguageListm`. Or `Show-Command -Name Get-ChildItem` -> `Get-ChildItemm`  !!!

Comment: `& (Show-Command -Name Get-WinUserLanguageList -PassThru)` as a workaround.

Comment: ok, but why does it only happen when I run it in Visual Studio Code and not in my Powershell ISE?